# Tor browser not opening

Tags: linux, browser, tor

Tor browser is not opening in my kali VM even though I am not logged on as root.
I also commented the code in 'Start tor browser' which displays an error if you enter as a root
As such no error is displayed, but this script opens up when I run start-tor-browser.desktop

```
#!/usr/bin/env ./Browser/execdesktop
#
# This file is a self-modifying .desktop file that can be run from the shell.
# It preserves arguments and environment for the start-tor-browser script.
#
# Run './start-tor-browser.desktop --help' to display the full set of options.
#
# When invoked from the shell, this file must always be in a Tor Browser root
# directory. When run from the file manager or desktop GUI, it is relocatable.
#
# After first invocation, it will update itself with the absolute path to the
# current TBB location, to support relocation of this .desktop file for GUI
# invocation. You can also add Tor Browser to your desktop's application menu
# by running './start-tor-browser.desktop --register-app'
#
# If you use --register-app, and then relocate your TBB directory, Tor Browser
# will no longer launch from your desktop's app launcher/dock. However, if you
# re-run --register-app from inside that new directory, the script
# will correct the absolute paths and re-register itself.
#
# This file will also still function if the path changes when TBB is used as a
# portable app, so long as it is run directly from that new directory, either
# via the shell or via the file manager.

[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Tor Browser Setup
GenericName=Web Browser
Comment=Tor Browser is +1 for privacy and -1 for mass surveillance
Categories=Network;WebBrowser;Security;
Exec=sh -c '"$(dirname "$*")"/Browser/start-tor-browser --detach || ([ ! -x "$(dirname "$*")"/Browser/start-tor-browser ] && "$(dirname "$*")"/start-tor-browser --detach)' dummy %k
X-TorBrowser-ExecShell=./Browser/start-tor-browser --detach
Icon=web-browser
StartupWMClass=Tor Browser
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Superuser! What do you mean `this script opens up`? How? In a text editor, just prints it.. or something else? Could you please give more info on what exactly happens when you try to open Tor Browser?

Comment: the script simply opens up in .txt file and that's it.No browser opens up

Answer (score 0):

Launch the browser with this command in the terminal (from your preferred file location, means where you kept the `start-tor-browser.desktop` file):

```
./start-tor-browser.desktop  --browser
```

or

```
./Browser/start-tor-browser --detach
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your directory to the directory where tor package is located.
For example, if it is located in the Downloads folder, use

```
cd Downloads
```

Now locate the tor folder(assume it to be tor-desktop)

```
cd tor-desktop
```

Head to the bin folder

```
cd bin
```

Now, start the browser using

```
./start-tor-browser.desktop --browser
```

The browser should open.